# Center aligning child divs and deal with float and fill

Tags: css, html, layout, css-float

Consider the following: http://jsfiddle.net/Yq39W/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="child1">
    Some text...
</div><div class="child2">
    2
</div><div class="child3">
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />        
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.child1, .child2, .child3 {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
}

.child1 {
    background:blue;
    float:left;
}

.child2 {
    height:200px;
    background:yellow;
}

.child3 {
    background:green;
    float:right;
}
```

How can I vertically center align the child divs, while child2 fills out the remaining space? (Meaning that the child1 and child3 will be moved down a little bit, so that the centers is aligned with center of child2)

What if height is NOT defined explicitly for any of the divs (in the example, child2 is explicitly set to 200px)? Is is still possible to align on the vertical axis?

It is important for me, that no dimensions are defined explicitly (except for parent width which would be 100% and any padding/margin on the elements).

Hope you guys can help out! :)

Comment: Do you mean *vertical centers* aligning with child2?

Comment: Why don't you make an image of what you want the div to look like, I think words are getting in the way of clarity in this instance.

Comment: Sorry guys! I meant vertically :) I have edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean *vertical centering* the child elements with child 2, then remove the `float`s and just add `vertical-align: middle;` since they are already `display: inline-block`. No need to declare a specific height, they'll all be vertically aligned with each other no matter what the tallest element is.

In the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/jnE89/), I use `<br />`s to make child 2 taller without an explicit height set just to demonstrate.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/jnE89/

You may want to set `max-width: 33%` for the children so that they won't go to multiple lines, but that just depends on the effect you're going for.

**Bonus:** If you want, you can use `text-align: justify` on the parent to ensure that your boxes cover the available space, like a grid (see [Text-align: Justify and RWD](http://www.barrelny.com/blog/text-align-justify-and-rwd/) or the [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shshaw/kX3uS/); note that the boxes must have spaces inbetween them in the HTML for it to work)

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. My follow-up question would have been how to right align/justify child3, but that seems to be done in your updated demo.